# Attempting to bring conan recipe from 1.x to new 2.x has stopped building static library

Tags: c++, conan, conan-2

I use a conan recipe to build a 3rd party set of libraries.. in the past it built a static library (`.a` file).. but now there are loads of deprecation warnings to upgrade .. although gitlab is still on 1.x support only.. I thought fine lets upgrade the recipe to get "ready"

however I can see that my recipe is not working as expected.. it should be building a library that is static `shared = false` .. but it is in fact doing an `.so` file.. indicating it is a shared library.

Anyone with experience with conan able to help?  I've search the docs and this seems not to jump out to me.

## ConanFile.py

```
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.files import files, copy
from conan.tools.layout import basic_layout
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, CMakeToolchain
import os
from os.path import join

MY_VERSION = "10.27.01"

BRANCH_NAME = "10.27.01_fix"


class MyApiConan(ConanFile):
    name = "myapi"
    version = MY_VERSION
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [ False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False}
    generators = "CMakeToolchain"

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone --depth 1 --branch " + BRANCH_NAME + " git@github.com:EMCP/my-api.git")

        files.replace_in_file(self, file_path="my-api/CMakeLists.txt", search="project( IBKR LANGUAGES CXX )",
                              replace='''project( MYAPI LANGUAGES CXX )
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)''')

    #        files.replace_in_file(self, file_path="my-api/CMakeLists.txt", search="         LANGUAGES CXX )",
#                              replace='''         LANGUAGES CXX )
#add_compile_options(-std=c++17)''')

    def layout(self):
        basic_layout(self, src_folder="src")

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.variables["BUILD_SHARED_LIBS"] = "OFF"  # Force static library
        tc.generate()

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(build_script_folder="my-api")
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()

        copy(self, "*.h", self.source_folder,   dst=join(self.package_folder, "include"), keep_path=False)
        copy(self, "*.lib", self.source_folder, dst=join(self.package_folder, "lib"), keep_path=False)
        copy(self, "*.dll", self.source_folder, dst=join(self.package_folder, "bin"), keep_path=False)
        copy(self, "*.so", self.source_folder, dst=join(self.package_folder, "lib"), keep_path=False)
        copy(self, "*.so", src=join(self.build_folder, "lib"), dst=join(self.package_folder, "lib"), keep_path=False)
        copy(self, "*.dylib", self.source_folder, dst=join(self.package_folder, "lib"), keep_path=False)
        copy(self, "*.a", self.source_folder, dst=join(self.package_folder, "lib"), keep_path=False)
        copy(self, "*.a", src=join(self.build_folder, "lib"), dst=join(self.package_folder, "lib"), keep_path=False)

        lib_paths = [
            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc000.a"
        ]
        for lib_path in lib_paths:
            if os.path.isfile(lib_path):
                self.output.info(f"Found library: {lib_path}")
                copy(self, pattern="libbidgcc000*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False, src="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
            else:
                self.output.warn(f"Library not found: {lib_path}")

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["twsapi"]
```

Comment: This is not C++

Comment: @Erik, please submit a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, this reads more like support, not QA, the issues are used also for support, not only for bug reports, and responses are quick

Comment: ``tc.variables["BUILD_SHARED_LIBS"] = "OFF"`` would be redundant, this is already done automatically by the ``CMakeToolchain``